# Getting django model entries with a more complex query (joining with no direct relationship)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to get the model entry for a certain query where I'm joining with columns that are not the ForeignKey of the table.

My tables (models) look like this (simplified with necessary columns):

```
class PE(models.Model): # table p_e
    p_e_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    p_o = models.ForeignKey('PO', models.DO_NOTHING)
    p_r = models.ForeignKey('PR', models.DO_NOTHING)
    s_o = models.ForeignKey('SO', models.DO_NOTHING)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Items, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='pe_item')
    p_e_is_possible = models.BooleanField()

class EIH(models.Model): # table e_i_h
    e_i_h_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    target_item = models.ForeignKey('Items', models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='target_item')
    component_item = models.ForeignKey('Items', models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='component_item')
    p_o = models.ForeignKey('PO', models.DO_NOTHING)
    p_r = models.ForeignKey('PR', models.DO_NOTHING)

class Items(models.Model):
    item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

The Query I am currently using without models looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM p_e
INNER JOIN e_i_h ON e_i_h.target_item_id = p_e.item_id AND e_i_h.component_item_id = -1  AND
    (e_i_h.p_o_id = p_e.p_o_id OR
    (p_e.p_e_is_possible = True AND p_e.s_o_id != -1)
    )
```

Is it possible to get the same queryset result as the Query only using models? The result is one entry from the table EIH with the query.

I tried to filter the EIH objects with joining over the items table:

```
pe_queryset = PE.objects.filter(item_id=15)
for pe in pe_queryset:
    erp = EIH.objects.get(Q(p_o_id= pe.p_o.p_o_id) | Q(pe.p_e_is_possible=True),
                          item_id=pe.item.item_id, component_item_id=-1)
```

I also tried lookup:

```
    erp = EIH.objects.get(Q(p_o_id= pe.p_o.p_o_id) | Q(target_item__p_e__p_e_is_possible=True),
          item_id=pe.item.item_id, component_item_id=-1)
```

The problem is the ERP model doesn't know `pe.p_e_is_possible` or `target_item__p_e__p_e_is_possible` so how can I add this Where statement to the EIH model to reproduce the result for the original query?

PS: Shortly summarized, I need to get the EIH with the related p_e_id.